# Авторизация Instagram на сайте

Tags: авторизация, instagram

Всем привет!!! Нужна помощь! Проблема следующая, сделал у себя на сайте авторизацию с помощью instagram, когда авторизуюсь со своего аккаунта, заходит нормально.С этого же аккаунта получал api.
Когда захожу с другого ошибка {"error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "code": 403, "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}
Кто сталкивался, прошу помощи, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы находитесь в режиме [песочницы](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/), необходимо отправить приложение на рассмотрение.